# Oracle collection

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, collections

I need to generate XML file in below structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root> 
  <header>………</header>  
  <module_info>……..</module_info> 
  <panel_info>…….</panel_info>  
  <process_area name= “XX”>    
    <panel_side name=”1”>   …..   </panel_side> 
    <panel_side name=”2”>   …..   </panel_side>  
  </process_area> 
  <process_area name=”XX”> 
    <panel_side name=”1”>   …..   </panel_side> 
    <panel_side name=”2”>   …..   </panel_side>  
  </process_area>  
  <process_area name=”XX”>
    <panel_side name=”1”>   …..   </panel_side> 
    <panel_side name=”2”>   …..   </panel_side> 
  </process_area> 
</root>
```

To achieve this,

1.Each tag in XML has more elements. We using Oracle DB. So we plan to get all the required data from DB. For this need to write Oracle pl/sql procedure or function that return all required data to build XML.

2.Based on the data which received from Oracle pl/sql, in Java we generate XML file looks like above.

Here the problem is the data which want return to Java is high. So the pl/sql procedure should return at-least more than 70 out parameters. To avoid this we plan to use **Oracle collections**.

What we planned is,

1.Create Record type for all the tags(Ex: header,module_info) with required fields. Also needs to create multilevel record type to maintain parent-child tag looks like below.

```
<process_area name= “XX”>    
    <panel_side name=”1”>   …..   </panel_side> 
    <panel_side name=”2”>   …..   </panel_side>  
</process_area>
```

2.Build record with value and return to Java. In this case also the plsql procedure have more than 8 out parameters(i.e Record/multilevel record type).

Is it good way or any other possibilities are there in Oracle to simplify?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just return as XML from the query?

Comment: Create the XML in Oracle and return it. Or return a RefCursor and loop through result in Java.

Comment: Oracle has a comprehensive XML capability built in to the database. There is simply no need to roll your own, especially not in Java. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb01int.htm).